# Showing that a series has radius of convergence equal to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

> Show that the series $\sum_{l \ge k}\binom{l} {k} z^{l-k}$ has radius of convergence equal $1$. And find a closed form for its sum.

**My attempt:**

$$\binom{l} {k} = \frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}$$

Let $a_l = \frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}$
And so lim as $l$ tends to infinity of $\frac{a_{l+1}}{a_l} = 1$.

And hence $R=1$

And what about the other part of the question? I don't know how to solve it and I didn't understand it. Any help please?

Comment: This may help! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: How would this help me

Comment: @JOJO because $z=z*1$ then apply binomial theorem with $(z+1)^l$

Comment: Can you see how the last equation from this paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement resembles your sum?

Comment: @LostInSpace okay I did, how does thos show that the series has radius of convergence =1

Comment: @JOJO this theorem is for the closed form of the sum

Comment: @LostInSpace so, is my attempt to prove R=1 correct?

Comment: @Marius is my attempt to show R=1 correct?